# Spring end to end test including filters and controller method using MockHttpServletRequest

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-test

I'm trying to write more of an end to end Spring test that will test my filters and the controller method associated to the given request.  I tried `RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handle()` but this doesn't call the filters. What classes do I need to use if I have a `MockHttpServletRequest` with a given path?  I don't want to call doFilter followed by handle. Instead, I'm looking to call the code that ultimately calls both of these methods.

EDIT: needs to work in Spring 3.1.

Answer (score 3):

You can register filters when you are setting up your `MockMvc` using [`MockMvcBuilders`](http://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/test/web/servlet/setup/MockMvcBuilders.html).

```
MockMvc mockMvc = MockMvcBuilders
          .webAppContextSetup(webApplicationContext)
          .addFilter(filter, urlPatterns);
```

The [javadoc](http://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/test/web/servlet/setup/AbstractMockMvcBuilder.html#addFilter-javax.servlet.Filter-java.lang.String...-) has more details. This method of registering filters is (mock-)equivalent to the web.xml configuration. For example

```xml
<filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>filter</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>
```

Comment: Uh oh, I only have Spring 3.1.  I'll add that to the question.

Comment: @JoshUnger I don't believe there is a nice way to do it. Consider upgrading. Otherwise, your solution seems appropriate.

Comment: You can still do it even with Spring 3.1 see https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-test-mvc/blob/master/src/test/java/org/springframework/test/web/server/samples/standalone/FilterTests.java but indeed upgrading to 3.2.8 or better yet 4.0.2 would be better.